# knockout observablearray not getting updated

Tags: knockout.js, jqxwidgets

I have an issue with updating an observableArray. I must be missing something here but what I have is this:

I have a list of values stored in my main viewmodel like this:

```
function AppViewModel() {
                var self = this;

                self.q1 = ko.observable().extend({ number: true });
                self.q2 = ko.observable().extend({ number: true });
                self.q3 = ko.observable().extend({ number: true });
                self.q4 = ko.observable().extend({ number: true });
                self.q5 = ko.observable().extend({ number: true });
.
.
.
```

I have a list of computed functions calculating Average values. I also have a separate viewmodel for creating a Chart using jqxWidgets. This is the code:

```
function ChartModel(scores) {
                var self = this;
                var cat;

                self.scores = ko.observableArray(scores);

                self.scores.push({ cat: "Re", score: vm.reAve() });
                self.scores.push({ cat: "Da", score: vm.daAve() });
                self.scores.push({ cat: "De", score: vm.deAve() });
                self.scores.push({ cat: "Im", score: vm.imAve() });
                self.scores.push({ cat: "Ps", score: vm.psAve() });
                self.scores.push({ cat: "Overall", score: vm.reAve() });

                //alert(self.scores()[0].score);
                self.updateScores = function () {
                    var item = {};

                    item.cat = "Re";
                    item.score = vm.reAve();
                    self.scores.replace(self.scores()[0], item);
                    item.cat = "Da";
                    item.score = vm.daAve();
                    self.scores.replace(self.scores()[1], item);
                    item.cat = "De";
                    item.score = vm.deAve();
                    self.scores.replace(self.scores()[2], item);
                    item.cat = "Im";
                    item.score = vm.imAve();
                    self.scores.replace(self.scores()[3], item);
                    item.cat = "Ps";
                    item.score = vm.psAve();
                    self.scores.replace(self.scores()[4], item);
                    item.cat = "Overall";
                    item.score = vm.basAve();
                    self.scores.replace(self.scores()[5], item);

                };

            }

            var vm = new AppViewModel();
            var cm = new ChartModel(scores);
```

I apply the bindings at the end of my `$(document).ready(...)` block. The issue is that the `scores` never gets updated when the updateScores function is called:

```
<button id="btnLoad" data-bind="click: cm.updateScores">View Chart</button>
```

Desperately need help/advice. 
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Have created a fiddle but unfortunately nothing works here. The radio buttons are supposed to update their respective observables and then calculate Total and Average values. It works fine in my project but I can't seem to reproduce it accurately in jsfiddle. Have been stuck on this the past hour. Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JPQ55/1/

What I'm struggling with in my project is that the observableArray values never get updated. Am sure I'm missing something but I don't know what...

**EDIT 2 :**

Ok, in my Questions model, I am trying to take the scores for 3 particular questions, store it in an observable array, and then calculate the maximum value that was chosen. I can't seem to get the UI to update to reflect the changes and console.log does not show me anything:

```
function CategoryModel(cat) {
                var self = this;

                self.name = cat.name;
                self.itemsChosen = ko.observable();
                self.catquestion = ko.utils.arrayMap(cat.qs, function (q) {
                    return new CatQuestionModel(q.label, q.number);
                });

                self.catTotalScore = ko.computed(function () {
                    var total = 0, numItems = 0;

                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.catquestion, function (question) {
                        // note that ~~ converts its operand to integer (or 0 if that fails)
                        total += ~ ~question.score() + ~~question.mdaScoreM();

                        if (!(isNaN(question.score()))) {
                            ++numItems;
                            self.itemsChosen(numItems);
                        }
                    });

                    return total;
                }, self);

                self.catAvgScore = ko.computed(function () {

                    return parseFloat(self.catTotalScore() / (self.itemsChosen() || 1)).toFixed(2);
                });
            }

            function CatQuestionModel(question, number) {
                var self = this;
                self.question = question;
                self.number = number;
                self.score = ko.observable();
                self.mdaScore = ko.observable();
                self.mdaVals = ko.observableArray([]);

                if (self.number == "2" || self.number == "3" || self.number == "4")
                    self.mdaVals.push(ko.observable({ "number": self.number, "score": self.mdaScore() }));

                self.mdaScoreM = ko.computed(function () {
                    var x = 0;

                    x = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.mdaVals(), function (i) {
                        return i.score === Math.max.apply(null, ko.utils.arrayMap(self.mdaVals(), function (e) {
                            return e.score;
                        }));
                    });

                    return x;
                }, self);

                self.mdaVals.notifySubscribers(self.mdaVals());
            }
```

mdaVals() is the array for holding all 3 values and mdaScore is supposed to be the max value obtained. Is there anything wrong with the above code?

Comment: Have you tried to use `data-bind="click: updateScores"`? You must not refer to `cm` in your view.

Comment: I've tried that, but I get "Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: updateScores is not defined;"

Comment: Is the `ChartModel` part of the `AppViewModel`? It's best if you set up a jsFiddle that shows your setup and reproduces your problem. Interactive guessing via question comments is the worst way to solve this.

Comment: I'll work on creating the fiddle (it's a long bit of html code). Btw the ChartModel is separate from the AppViewModel.

Comment: Try to reduce it to the absolute minimum that still reproduces your problem.

Comment: @Tomalak I've attached the fiddle in my edits. But can't quite reproduce the problem. Have tried to explain the issue. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: You cannot call `applyBindings()` twice, at least not like that. There can only be one view model per page, unless you define separate areas (like, `<div>` elements) and apply bindings to them specifically.

Comment: And another general hint: If you find yourself creating variable names with a trailing counter (like `q15`), then you're definitely doing something wrong. Refactor your code to use an array.

Comment: Here is how your view model *should* look like: http://jsfiddle.net/JPQ55/2/. I suggest you study the fiddle closely, I've changed quite a lot. If you are writing new code (as opposed to fixing an existing app) I also suggest you use the current version of Knockout, the version you started with (2.2.1) is very old.

Comment: You need to define scores that is getting passed into the ChartModel constructor.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks! I'm going through your code now. This definitely seems a much better way of doing things (I'm still pretty green at KO I guess). Am going to go through this carefully and see how my chart model gets updated. Will update you in a little bit.

Comment: @WayneEllery Aye, I figured that much. Now with the array that Tomalak created in the latest fiddle, I shall do that. Thank you.

Comment: @Tomalak Quick question. I need to store the question number as well. In the fiddle, I only included the scoring for the first column "Relation to self/others". There are a couple of more columns, each associated with different questions. For eaxmple, the "Psychosis" column will read the scores for Qs 22,23,24 and 27. Would you suggest adding another variable "QNumber" when binding the AppViewModel?

Comment: Sorry I need to rephrase that question. There is a number in Question model, but after I get all the scores into the array, how would I match them to their relevant category?

Comment: If you have a structure "above" the question level then your data model must include that structure. "Category" sure sounds like that. You need an array of category objects, each of which contains a category id and an array of questions. Once you have that you can ramp up your view model to reflect that. And than you can ramp up your view accordingly. If different categories can have different answers with different scores, put a set of answers into each category object. In any case your data model must be sound before you do anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have created an array of category objects, each containing their relevant questions. Have updated all the views accordingly. Everything works fine now, thanks to both you and @Wayne who helped me answer another question related to this topic. So now I am back to the question of how to update my observableArray. The array contains observable values as well. But I figured they would automatically be updated when their values change. Maybe I'm not understanding it well enough...

Comment: @Tomalak not sure if you were notified of the previous comment and EDITs so am adding another one (still getting the hang of using SO.

Comment: Surely I have been notified, I must have missed it though. Are you sure you want to push `"score": self.mdaScore()`? That would push a fixed value. Maybe you want to push `"score": self.mdaScore` instead? Also, calling `notifySubscribers()` should hardly ever be necessary in a normal Knockout app. -- Since this question has turned into an interactive debugging session (and that's not the point of SO) I suggest: Make a new fiddle. Strip off *everything* not directly related to your problem, i.e. recreate your problem from scratch in ~20 LOC or less. Ask a new question with a precise focus.

Comment: @user3713861 If you want the value on the page to be updated when a value on an object inside the array changes you need to declare each value on the object as an observable. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value on the page to be updated when a value on an object inside the array changes you need to declare each value on the object as an observable.

```
self.mdaVals = ko.observableArray([]);

self.mdaVals.push({ number: ko.observable(1), score: ko.observable(20)});

self.mdaVals()[0].number(2);

self.mdaVals()[0].score(10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tm5J9/1/

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I had passed in observable values into the array. (self.mdaScore() is an observable). But the main issue was that I should have removed the parentheses.